# Veeam Agent for Linux not connecting to SMB from FreeNAS

Tags: backup, cifs, truenas, veeam, smbclient

I want to backup an Ubuntu 16.04 server using Veeam Agent for Linux free edition. I'm trying to do the backups to an SMB/CIFS password protected share created in FreeNAS but am getting a password error in Veeam even though I can connect via command line using `smbclient`. Here are the steps to reproduce ...

I start the Veeam Agent for Linux and enter the SMB info to my FreeNAS SMB share like this:

[image: Image of SMB configuration]

Then select Next and get the following **error**:

```
Broadcast message from root@servername (Thu 2017-08-17 16:10:03 PDT):
Password entry required for 'Password for 123.456.654.321@//data:' (PID 6733).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!
```

After a little while then this additional **error** pops up:

[image: Image of error]

*NOTE: I can successfully connected to the FreeNAS SMB server using command line from this machine by doing `smbclient //123.456.654.321/data -U someuser` and then entering the password. But to get that command to work I first had to Stop then Start SMB from the FreeNAS GUI.*

**I don't know why these errors are happening and don't know how to further diagnose???**

Comment: HELP: I attached images of the configuration and error, but it's not graphically showing, only as a link. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Add an exclamation mark (`!`) in front of the image to make it show up directly, I edited your post accordingly. I also use Veeam agent for linux and got it working with an SMB share. I will see if I can spot anything fishy in your configuration.

Comment: Can you try to mount the share directly (not with `smbclient` but a real `mount` command)? If that fails try in verbose mode (`-v`) and see what it complains about. Also what does your `/var/log/veeam/config/veeamconfig.log` say in regards to mounting? Maybe also look in the other files there. A look at the SMB log on the server might also be worthwhile. And last but not least: you can open a case at the Veeam support. They also help with the free edition. Right now I also have an open case there for the free edition.